# oracle - Calculate sum or avg in one query based on the their value

Tags: oracle, plsql

I've this table

| date | customer | amount | percentage | category |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 20220330 | customer1 | 10 | 93 | 01 |
| 20220330 | customer1 | 11 | 91 | 01 |
| 20220330 | customer1 | 13 | 91 | 02 |
| 20220330 | customer1 | 15 | 91 | 02 |

I' need to calculate

`sum of percentage if amount it not null and gt zero and category is 01`

otherwise

`avg of percentage if amount is not null and gt zero and category is 02`

all this in only one query and grouped by date and customer

It's possible?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

See if this (conditional aggregate) helps.

Sample data:

```
SQL> with test (datum, customer, amount, percentage, category) as
  2    (select 20220330, 'customer1', 10, 93, '01' from dual union all
  3     select 20220330, 'customer1', 11, 91, '01' from dual union all
  4     select 20220330, 'customer1', 13, 91, '02' from dual union all
  5     select 20220330, 'customer1', 15, 91, '02' from dual
  6    )
```

Query begins here:

```
  7  select
  8    datum,
  9    customer,
 10    sum(case when amount is not null and category = '01' then percentage end) res_sum,
 11    avg(case when amount is not null and category = '02' then percentage end) res_avg
 12  from test
 13  group by datum, customer;

     DATUM CUSTOMER     RES_SUM    RES_AVG
---------- --------- ---------- ----------
  20220330 customer1        184         91

SQL>
```

---

A few notes:

- I have no idea what "and gt zero" means. If you do (I *guess* you do), include it into the query
- `date` is reserved for datatype; generally speaking, you can't name column like that (unless you enclose its name into double quotes)

  - you shouldn't store dates as strings. Maybe you just *interpreted* 30th of March 2022 as "20220330", can't tell - just saying

Comment: "gt" most likely means "greater than".

Comment: I'm sorry, gt means greater than. Date name field is only for indicate a column type. Obviously real column name is different. In the first query you make specific search but, I don't know at prior the content of table.

Comment: If "I don't know at prior the content of table" regards lines #1 - 6, then: as stated, that's just sample data - you won't type that. Query - as stated, again - begins at line #7 - that's the query you need.